# using the brush assembly and Aerovac bin space?

Tags: irobot-create

A lot of the Create 2's interior space is taken up by the brush assembly and the Aerovac bin.  I'd like to take these out and put in my own stuff, but I'm concerned that the Roomba might get confused by the fact that I've unplugged these items.  Is there anything special I need to do, aside from adding an appropriate amount of weight in that area?

Answer (score 1):

No need to fear.  The Roomba will run just fine without the brush deck, vacuum bin, and side brush motor.

Be sure to check out http://www.irobot.com/create where there are 3D files for an extended bottom half of the vacuum bin to hold your stuff.  There are even mounting posts for Arduino, RaspberryPi, and RaspberryPi2.